# Is it typo in book?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Above the "yesterday" block  should be finished?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Jeremen. Thanks for selecting my answer but I recommend waiting for others to answer. That's how this site works. Let others may come up with their answers and wait at least for some hours if not a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I daresay, **both** should have 'finished'. When you say *I'm **done** with it** no matter which tense (I was, had...anything) it means *finished*.

> I've done a lot of work today - I guess, it's *done* and that's it. **Or else it'd be something like...**
>
> I've *been* doing a lot of work today (the work is continued... and yet not finished).

The other one...

> I did a lot of work yesterday - certainly, the work **is** finished here.

Let others come and I'll probably learn on this. Good question (+1) :)